# java sql exception syntax error in from clause

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc-odbc

I have an access database and trying to use it in java. I want to select it and wrote a statement as

```
String sql="SELECT * from numeric;";
    try
    {
        rs=s.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
    }
```

The executeQuery is throwing an exception as

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in
>    FROM clause.

I think the select statement I wrote is correct. Even if i write as

> SELECT Webservice FROM numeric;

also gives me an error where Webservice is my column name.

Comment: Isn't `numeric` some kind of SQL data type? Try to put the name into paranthesis, i.e. use `[numeric]`. Are you sure you have named your table `numeric`?

Comment: @D.R. Yes, I have kept the table name as numeric. But i will change the table name and try. thank you.

Comment: @D.R. It is exactly the thing that you have mentioned. The fault is with the table name only. Once I have changed it, the execution is done without error. Thank you. I can upvote the comment as I cannot mark it as an answer. please leave as an answer for others.

Comment: I've converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is called `numeric` which is also an SQL data type. The SQL parser thinks its a data type and your query fails. If you have reserved keywords like this as table names you need to put the table name in parenthesis:

`SELECT * FROM [numeric]`

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove the trailing `;` at the end of your statement!

Usually you are seperating statements with a `;`, but since executing multiple statements in a single statement string is not allowed in JDBC by specification, you can't use semicolons.

Comment: Actually we can use ; because I am using ODBC drivers. It doesn't give me any error with semicolon. I changed the table name and it is working fine now. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Access database the index starts from one, not zero. Identify the index of `webservice` first, it mary be two, try out the following statement

```
System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
```

Comment: If you look at the exception `Syntax error in FROM clause.` the issue is probably not the call of `getString`, is it?

Comment: yes,  even if correct from clause may some times unable to get the value.

Comment: It is not an error. And the first one column is Webservice. The table name is only an error.